# File Path Management in a Nextflow Pipeline

Tags: bioinformatics, nextflow, cromwell

I have a `.config` file containing directory paths for various tools. I want to isolate a single filepath, for example: `/mount1/nextflow_dir/`, and for the other tools, I would like to add something as simple as demonstrated in the Python code below:

```
import os
tool1_fp = os.path.join(main_config, 'tool1')
tool2_fp = os.path.join(main_config, 'tool2')
```

Is there a way to perform this directory in NextFlow using google language or otherwise, instead of depending on an additional pyhton or bash script?

Comment: I tried this already; `tool1 = join(main_config, 'tool1')`, I get nextflow annotation **nextflow.extension.OpCall@16bd7ae1**.

Comment: Are you trying to add an homemade script to your path?

Comment: Something as simple as just adding `config_directory` which is `/mount/tools` to a directory `tools1`.

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to fix it `tool1_fp = "$main_config/tools1"`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using;

```
tool1_fp = "$main_config/tools1"
```